# How to use Buttons to run alternate Manipulate functions

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I wish to use Buttons to trigger alternate Manipulates.

According to the documentation:  "The first argument to Button is the label"  ....and the "second argument is the function that will evaluate when you click the button." (source:  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToControlObjects.html

Here is simple code which works and runs a Manipulate

```
Remove[a, b, ma, mb]
ma[a_, b_] := a^2 + b
Manipulate[ma[a, b], {{a, 1}, 0, 5}, {{b, 1}, 0, 5}]
```

And here is modified example which SHOULD work via button according to the documentation (unless Manipulate is not in fact a function!).  This code does NOT work.

```
Remove[a, b, ma, mb]
ma[a_, b_] := a^2 + b
Button["Crazy Dead Button",Manipulate[ma[a, b], {{a, 1}, 0, 5}, {{b, 1}, 0, 5}]]
```

The documentation is leading me astray.  Only some functions can be triggered this way I guess.  But why not, and what is easiest way to fix the code?

Comment: Try `Button["Crazy Dead Button", 
 Print@Manipulate[ma[a, b], {{a, 1}, 0, 5}, {{b, 1}, 0, 5}], 
 Method -> "Queued"]`?

Comment: Or `Button["Crazy Dead Button", CellPrint[Manipulate[ma[a, b], {{a, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]]`

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here. The first one can be explained easily because you simply forgot that your button needs to *do something*. Just evaluating your `Manipulate` is not going to do what you like, because you need to *see* it on screen when you want to interact with it. Therefore, you need to `Print` or `CellPrint` your `Manipulate`.

The second issue arises when you use a button, which is a dynamic object to create another dynamic object. Both rely on the same infrastructure and you need to be careful. The whole story behind this is too long to be explained here but a good start is the advanced dynamic tutorial in the documentation. Nevertheless, two solutions as posted in the comments by kguler and Bob

```
Button["Crazy Dead Button", Print@Manipulate[ma[a, b], {{a, 1}, 0, 5},
  {{b, 1}, 0, 5}], Method -> "Queued"]

Button["Crazy Dead Button", CellPrint[Manipulate[ma[a, b], 
  {{a, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]]
```

Comment: Manipulate is a function, though a complex one.  If a properly formed Manipulate function is encountered in an Input cell, it will generate an Output cell.  You do not have to hit it with Print, or CellPrint.  But if it is encountered inside a properly formed Button function, it will not execute, it will not generate the Output cell.  It seems to me this is a bug in Mathematica.  Either Button[] will execute some functions and not others, or Manipulate will execute if it is encountered in some properly formed functions but not others.  I don't know which.  What do you think?