# How to make a button that allow me to control a Manipulate module?

Tags: manipulate, interface, button

I'm trying to use button that allow me to control a manipulate module.

Here's what I did now, it's really simple:

```
Orbits = Manipulate[Graphics[{Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Red, PointSize[.04], 
 Point[{Cos[2*t], Sin[2*t]}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 3}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
ImageSize -> 450], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, 
ControlType -> Trigger}]; 
firstorbits = Button["1s", Orbits]
```

However, for some reason I can't let the Manipulate module display after I click the button, so should I try ControlType?

Comment: Try `CellPrint@Orbits`. I think this is good question. "What is the difference between Shift+Return and pressing the Button", it is not obvious for new users. There are duplicates for sure but it may be hard to find them.

Comment: @Kuba Perhaps you should post that as an answer ... BTW Can you find a descriptive title or keywords for this kind of problems? They keep coming :)

Comment: @belisarius it would be nice to have more explanatory answer, which I don't have time to make :) but I will convert my comment into the answer if it stays unanswered to long :)

Comment: @belisarius ha, this is a good one [83196](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83196/5478). About keywords, Button+CellPrint, if you know there is a duplicate, look for the most obvious answer :P

Comment: @belisarius still, linked answer does not contain the explanation I'd like to see in such case.

Comment: @Kuba, "you need to see it on screen....Therefore, you need to `Print` or `CellPrint`..." seems a sufficient explanation to me.  -- Or you could add an answer there, when you have time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah but why you can see this after Shift+Return even without  Print. I don't know I'm trying to put myself in newbie position.

Comment: @Kuba You mean that evaluating an expression and printing the value in the notebook are thought to be the same by a confused user?  I guess that's reasonable.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, and the fact there is a duplicate, and I think more of them too means it is really the case,